# What is the easiest way to create an Enumeration<T> object containing a single T value in java?

Tags: java, generics, enumeration

Generally, I want to know what is the most convenient and readable approach to generate an `Enumeration<T>` object from a given single `T` object in java.

In my case I have a `String` object which I need to wrap into an `Enumeration<T>`. I need to interoperate with legacy APIs that require an enumeration as input.

This is what I am doing:

```
public Enumeration<String> getEnumeration(String value) {
     Vector<String> result = new Vector<>();
     result.add(value);
     return result.elements();
}
```

Is there any other approach which is more succinct?
Thanks

Comment: @BasilBourque It is a very common java framework which wants me to use `Enumeration`.

Comment: I added a mention of that to your Question to deflect the distraction of `Enumeration` being very old legacy code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html).

```
import java.util.Collections;
...
return Collections.enumeration( Collections.singleton(value) );
```